# Understanding lapply for list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I am cleaning a group of text files, currently operating on them as a list of data frames with identical structure.

Given the structure of the text files, there ends up being an irregular cell in each df. This cell contains a string which contains a column name and value. I need to extract the value and assign it to a new column and then do some other reassigning to get the desired clean dfs. Ultimately, I know what I need to do on the data itself, but I am stuck figuring out how to operate on the list of dfs for this particular problem.

*Minimal data example:*

```r
x = data.frame(V1 = c(1, 2, "Column name: 1.18"), V2 = c(1, 2, ""), V3 = c(1, 2, ""),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

                 V1 V2 V3
1                 1  1  1
2                 2  2  2
3 Column name: 1.18

list_x = list(x, x)

[[1]]
                 V1 V2 V3
1                 1  1  1
2                 2  2  2
3 Column name: 1.18      

[[2]]
                 V1 V2 V3
1                 1  1  1
2                 2  2  2
3 Column name: 1.18
```

I've been using mainly lapply to clean the dfs, but only for adding/removing rows/columns and setting names. This works as I expect.

I thought that lapply would work for the irregular cell, but I'm not understanding how to get at the data generally within the list of dfs. What I do that works on a single df does not on the list. My misunderstanding is in how to assign the output of lapply to the original dfs. I've read several resources and SO questions on operating on lists of dfs, but have not come up with a solution.

*My lapply function:*

```r
list_x = lapply(list_x, function(x) gsub("Column name: ", "", x[3,1]))

[[1]]
[1] "1.18"

[[2]]
[1] "1.18"
```

I expected the assignment with lapply to work on the data within the dfs, however, it assigns each list to only the output of gsub, getting rid of the rest of the data.

This was my strategy because it's how I came up with the correct data structure while working through the problem on a single df:

```r
x2 = x
x2[3,1] = gsub("Column name: ", "", x2[3,1])
x2$V4 = 0
x2$V4[3] = as.numeric(x2$V1[3])
x2[3,1] = "3"
x2[x2==""] = 0

  V1 V2 V3   V4
1  1  1  1 0.00
2  2  2  2 0.00
3  3  0  0 1.18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intention is to create four columns, after looping through the `list` with `lapply`, extract the numeric part from the 3rd row of 1st column, and `cbind` with the already existing columns of the dataset by appending 0.

```
lapply(list_x, function(x)  rbind(head(cbind(x, V4 = 0), -1), 
     rep(c(3, 0, as.numeric(gsub("[^.0-9]+", "", x[3, 1]))), c(1, 2, 1)) ))
#[[1]]
#  V1 V2 V3   V4
#1  1  1  1 0.00
#2  2  2  2 0.00
#3  3  0  0 1.18

#[[2]]
#  V1 V2 V3   V4
#1  1  1  1 0.00
#2  2  2  2 0.00
#3  3  0  0 1.18
```

---

Or another option is to create a function to apply over the `list` of data.frames

```
f1 <- function(x) {i1 <- grep("Column name", x$V1)
       v1 <- as.numeric(sub(".*\\s([0-9.]+)$", "\\1", x$V1[i1]))
       x1 <- x[-i1,]
       x1$V4 <- 0
       rbind(x1, list(V1 = 3, V2 = 0, V3 = 0, V4 = v1))
        }
lapply(list_x, f1)
#[[1]]
#  V1 V2 V3   V4
#1  1  1  1 0.00
#2  2  2  2 0.00
#3  3  0  0 1.18

#[[2]]
#  V1 V2 V3   V4
#1  1  1  1 0.00
#2  2  2  2 0.00
#3  3  0  0 1.18
```

Comment: Your first answer works well. My actual dfs are larger than my example, but easy enough to work out the correct dims.

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to make it work for your one dataframe and every dataframe in list of dataframes follows the same structure, put it in in one function and use `lapply` to apply function to each dataframe in the list

```
apply_fun <- function(x2)  {
    x2[3,1] = sub("Column name: ", "", x2[3,1])
    x2$V4 = 0
    x2$V4[3] = as.numeric(x2$V1[3])
    x2[3,1] = 3
    x2[x2==""] = 0
    x2
}

lapply(list_x, apply_fun)

#[[1]]
#  V1 V2 V3   V4
#1  1  1  1 0.00
#2  2  2  2 0.00
#3  3  0  0 1.18

#[[2]]
#  V1 V2 V3   V4
#1  1  1  1 0.00
#2  2  2  2 0.00
#3  3  0  0 1.18
```